# IBM Worklight - How to add multi-language support?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-runtime

How do you add multi-language support in a Worklight app? Can anyone give me some example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the file common/js/messages.js

Use this istruction for the loading

```
if(WL.App.getDeviceLanguage() == 'en' && WL.App.getDeviceLocale() == 'en-US') {
    WL.ClientMessages.loading = 'Custom Loading Message';
}
```

and

```
WL.ClientMessages.loading = Messages.wrklight;
```

[Here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/dev/c_globalization_in_ibm_worklight.html) the doc

Answer (score 3):

There is documentation about how to do it with Worklight: [http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.help.doc%2Fwl_home.html](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.help.doc/wl_home.html)

You can use Cordova API to detect the language and write code built on it: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/cordova_globalization_globalization.md.html
If you are using Dojo in your application you can use the http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/quickstart/internationalization/
and
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/quickstart/internationalization/globalization-guidelines/
If you are using jQuery there are plugins that do that as well, like: https://code.google.com/p/jquery-i18n-properties/